# Windows Server 2008 R2 restore question

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'd like to make a backup/image of my machine, so that I may install it if i ever need to.
What I mean by image is a snapshot of all of my programs, settings,files, everything, i think this is referred to as a ghost image.
I want to be able to restore so I do not have to reinstall everything again.
Does the backup/restore utility in Windows Server 2008 R2 do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

FYI - Ghost is a specific application made by Symantec that makes image-based backups. A Ghost image is one that's been created by this application. An image-based backup is the generic cross-product term for it.

Comment: does Windows 7 do the image thing?

Comment: @user8160: Yes-- Windows Backup in Windows 7 will also make image backups, stored in the form of Microsoft Virtual Hard Drive (VHD) files.